# How to programmatically write text to the developer's clipboard?

Tags: flutter, dart

When debugging a Flutter applications, the `debugPrint()` call writes text to the console. I want to do something similar, but instead of writing to the console, I want to write to the developer's clipboard so they can paste the text somewhere.

So, if I'm developing an Android app with Flutter on a Mac, I want to write the dump to Mac's clipboard, not the Android emulator's.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not possible from within your Flutter code. The emulator would need to have this functionality built-in.

Comment: Use clipboard package, https://pub.dev/packages/clipboard I am developing on a mac m1 and its working for me!

Comment: Thanks @SuvashBhandari! I does this package also work within Flutter widget tests? I should have included that requirement in my OP.

Comment: I haven't tried it, so couldn't really say anything about that!

Comment: Ah. pub.dev/packages/clipboard didn't copy to the clipboard for me. I installed their sample line from the ReadMe into Flutter code and widget tests tests and it didn't copy to the mac's clipboard.